# Angular 7 - nested form touched flag interferes with parent form button click

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a parent form and a few nested components within it. The parent form has the submit button which upon click should trigger all field validations to come up. Each nested component has field validations that should come up on combination of "touched" and invalid. What happens is if the user is focused within one of the nested components inputs, the parent form doesn't register the submit button click (as if the first click is to focus out of the component's input, and then the second click will register the button click). If I change the touched flag to "dirty", while its not the behavior I want, the submit button does register the click. Please help :)

Parent Form:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  parentForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      planetsForm: this.formBuilder.group({
        planets: ['', [Validators.required]]
      }),
      fruitsForm: this.formBuilder.group({
        fruits: ['', [Validators.required]
      })
   });

   isFieldInvalid(field: FormControl) {
      return field.errors && field.touched; //this is the touched that gives me trouble 
   }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("clicked"); //Doesnt get called when the cursor is focused within the planets or fruits input box
    this.validateAllFormFields(this.parentForm);
  }

  validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
     Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
     const control = formGroup.get(field);
     if (control instanceof FormControl) {
       control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
     } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
       this.validateAllFormFields(control);
     }
  });

}
```

Parent Form HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="parentForm" novalidate>

    <app-planets [group]="parentForm.get('planetForm')" [hasError]="isFieldInvalid(parentForm.get('planetForm').get('planets'))">

    <app-fruits [group]="parentForm.get('fruitForm')" [hasError]="isFieldInvalid(parentForm.get('fruitForm').get('fruits'))">

    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Child component(planets and fruits the same):

```
export class AppPlanetsComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() hasError;
   @Input() group: FormGroup;

   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

   ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Child component(planets and fruits the same):

```
 <div class="form-inline" [formGroup]="group">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 form-group form-group-padding">  
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 no-padding">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control full-width" id="fruits" formControlName="fruits">
                </div>  

                <div *ngIf="hasError">
                     This is a dummy error message!
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Resolved it - the blur event fires before the click event which is why it didnt register. The mousedown event however is triggered before blur.